# Generic Method of Searching all Fields within an IEnumerable for any match in c#

Tags: c#

I code below that works well with an API for the DataTables plugin; for each column that the DataTables searches in, regardless of type, the filter works as expected based on what is supplied.

DataTables also has a "Global" search feature where you can search in one field and if there is a match in ANY of the rows for said data then a match is returned.

### What I am Hoping For:

A way to perform a search on an IEnumerable such that if any of the fields match the search the result is returned.

```
NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);

var generalSearch = nvc["sSearch"];
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(generalSearch))
{
    var generalSearchProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var currentProperty in generalSearchProperties)
    {
        Type propType = currentProperty.PropertyType;
        set = set.Where(StaticUtility.PropertyEquals<T>(currentProperty, generalSearch, propType));
        /*        ^^^^^        */
        /*
        Instead of the "Where" here I am looking for something like "where or" which can be added to the IEnumerable.
        */
    }
}
```

### Original Code:

```
protected virtual IQueryable<T> FilterEntitiesBySearchParameters(IQueryable<T> set)
{
    try
    {
        NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
        var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var name = prop.Name;
            var val = nvc[name];
            Type propType = prop.PropertyType;
            if (val != null)
            {
                set = set.Where(StaticUtility.PropertyEquals<T>(prop, val, propType));
            }
            if (nvc.GetPairs().Where(p => p.Value == name).Where(p => p.Key.StartsWith("mDataProp")).Any())
            {
                var key = nvc.GetPairs().Where(p => p.Value == name).Where(p => p.Key.StartsWith("mDataProp")).FirstOrDefault().Key;
                key = key.Replace("mDataProp", "sSearch");
                val = nvc[key];
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                    set = set.Where(StaticUtility.PropertyEquals<T>(prop, val, propType));
            }
        }
        return set;
    } catch (Exception exc)
    {
        return set;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Where or"? .Any will return true if there is any match

Comment: @ZivWeissman That is correct. On any member of Type T that matches the supplied search parameter return a match.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your request correctly, you basically want to search through your data and match any field for equality?  If that's true, then simply add your matching data to a new set, and filter it by `.Distinct()` after the fact, to make sure you get one record of each. Something like so...

```
NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
var results = new IEnumerable<T>();

var generalSearch = nvc["sSearch"];
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(generalSearch))
{
    var generalSearchProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var currentProperty in generalSearchProperties)
    {
        Type propType = currentProperty.PropertyType;
        results.AddRange(set.Where(StaticUtility.PropertyEquals<T>(currentProperty, generalSearch, propType)));

    }
}
return results.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to first create a `BinaryExpression` consisting of all the different options, then pass that expression to the `Where()` method of the query.

Assuming your `StaticUtility` class is used to create expressions, you might try something like the following:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);

// Container for filter expression
BinaryExpression filter = null;

var generalSearch = nvc["sSearch"];
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(generalSearch)) {
    var generalSearchProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var currentProperty in generalSearchProperties) {
        Type propType = currentProperty.PropertyType;

        if (filter == null) {
            // Start with first filter expression
            filter = StaticUtility.PropertyEquals<T>(currentProperty, generalSearch, propType);
        } else {
            // Add another filter using OR
            BinaryExpression other = StaticUtility.PropertyEquals<T>(currentProperty, generalSearch, propType);
            filter = BinaryExpression.OrElse(filter, other);
        }
    }
}

// Add actual filter to query
set = set.Where(filter);
```